# eosio/eos-dev docker is not producing blocks

Tags: block-producer, docker

Hi sorry if my question seems basic.
I'm running eosio/eos-dev docker and when I run the command `docker logs --tail 10 nodeos` I don't see any block producing. This is the log I'm seeing:

```
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/chain/get_transaction_id
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/chain/push_block
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/chain/push_transaction
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/chain/push_transactions
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   history_api_plugin.cpp:38     plugin_startup       ] starting history_api_plugin
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/history/get_actions
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/history/get_controlled_accounts
2018-09-13T09:29:05.399 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/history/get_key_accounts
2018-09-13T09:29:05.400 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:447           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/history/get_transaction
2018-09-13T09:29:05.400 thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:3010           plugin_startup       ] starting listener, max clients is 25
```

I already removed and restart docker container and it doesn't solve the solution.
Everything seems working fine but blocks are not producing in blockchain.

Comment: Can't help without more info. Are you following the explanation at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart ?

Comment: did you pass `nodeos` the `-e -p eosio` flags?